# Testing string for words with 3 repeated consecutive characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get a Regex expression that will be satisfied when given a string that has at least 1 word composed of 3 or more repeating consecutive characters, and no other characters:

`Testing AAAAAA Test` - Valid

`Testing AAAAAAB Test` - Invalid

The previous solution I had reached was not enough to recognize if there were different characters in the word:

`/^(?:(.)(?!\1{2}))+$/gi`

This was essentially just testing if the 2 characters after each character are equal to it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show more sample inputs / expected outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
\b(.)\1{2,}\b
```

which is

```
\b    word boundary
(.)   something
\1    previous thing...
{2,}  ...twice or more
\b    word boundary
```

https://regex101.com/r/BKHkOc/3

Answer (score 1):

Add word boundaries. And use `{2,}` to match *at least 2* repetitions.

```
/\b(.)\1{2,}\b/
```

There's no need for `i`, since you're not matching letters, so case is irrelevant. And `g` is not needed when just testing; it's only useful if you're returning all the matches or doing a replacement.